# Assign tasks to multiple users using workflow without Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

My requirement is, we want our employees to read a document whenever the administrator asks them to.

For this I can manually start a workflow against a document. The problem is, I can only create one associated task. Can I do a "for each" to create multiple tasks using SharePoint Designer?

How is it possible to create multiple tasks for each user (workflow can be one), without using a Visual Studio solution?

Comment: How are you capturing the users? You can do multiple tasks in a designer workflow, but what kicks off their tasks?

Comment: My initial idea was to capture users through the Document property. Unfortunately the initialization parameters don't let you select users. When the workflow starts, it will kick off everyone's task. Someone has to start the workflow in order for the selected users to read that document.

Comment: You can have a custom "People/Group" type column that you can specify the users or a group of the people you want to have tasks. Then in the workflow you can pull that column in and create a task for all the users in that group.

Comment: ok. but for that I need to define the exact People/group in the workflow. Actually this is supposed to be a runtime variable. Even if I had the People/Group column in the document library, I will then have to edit the column value in order for me to get the users I want in the workflow.

Comment: It can be a initialization variable.

Comment: Eventually I decided to use Sharepoint Learning Kit from codeplex. It meets our requirements and there is no development required.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was done a while ago, but I thought I would share a very simple solution to this kind of problem (if I understand the problem correctly).

If the users to perform a task are to be specified during the initiation of the workflow, then you simply need to create an 'Assignment Stages' Initiation Form parameter. Then you can use that field to populate the 'Participants' in the workflow action.

[image]

When you start the workflow, you will be taken to the initiation form which will include a repeatable table to specify the users and the assignment order in it. Then when done, click start, and your workflow will perform that action for those users in the order you specified.

Comment: Thanks for opening this topic again. Is this possible in SharePoint Foundation 2010?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood questions correctly than, if all you want to do is require a list of user (group of people) to perform same task and wait until all of them complete it than why not do "Assign a custom form to these users" or "Assign a to-do item to these users". it is listed under Action-> Task Actions.

Answer (score 0):

hi please refer this link:

http://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-tutorials/Assigning-task-multiple-users/144025/161254-4.html?vid=2&type=2

and also this link using visual studio:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffca6f38-f7b4-4f23-b23d-65291f3f7997/how-to-assign-values-to-workflow-task-person-or-group-custom-field?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Try to include the good parts from the links in your post, and only use the links as a source to more information. If the links break your answer will be of no help to future readers